# Using cp in bash to update file information or rename

Tags: bash, cp

This is my first script using bash and I am creating it to take user input check a directory and see if that file is already in the directory and if it is already backed up, if not take the file and copy it over to a back up. However once the code runs it fires the first if statement and alerts me of the file being in the directory however it fails to create the the backup. If how I understand copy command I should first use `cp` then (file A) to (file A backup)

```
B1="${1}_bck1"
B2="${1}_bck2"
#echo $1 contains the first the u typed on the command line after the script
if [ -e $1 ]
    then 
        echo "The file already exists"
        fi
        if [ -e $B1 ]
            then
                cp $B1 $B2
                fi
if [ -e $B1 ]
    then
        echo ${1}
        cp $1 $B1 
        mv $B1 test
        fi      
    else 
        echo "The file does not exist"
        exit
fi
```

Edit1. I added in the fi statement to close the argument if the file is already in the directory. I now get a token else error?

Answer (score 2):

The code is badly formatted and indented in confusing ways.

Makes it very hard for you or anyone to see what's really happening.
There is an extra 'fi' in before an 'else', that's screwing things up big time, for starters.

After formatting it I can see the structure and what's going on and errors become immediately obvious, which is why you need to have discipline for how you lay out your code. Here's what I see by simply indenting things better and reducing vertical space:

**SYNTACTIC CLEANUP (ONLY) OF ORIGINAL CODE**

```
#/bin/bash
B1="${1}_bck1"
B2="${1}_bck2"
if [ -e $1 ]; then 
    echo "The file already exists"
fi
if [ -e $B1 ]; then
    cp $B1 $B2
fi
if [ -e $B1 ]; then
        echo ${1}
        cp $1 $B1 
        mv $B1 test
fi      
else 
    echo "The file does not exist"
    exit
fi
```

You check for existence of $B1 twice in a row.
Why not put all of the code you execute if B1 exists in the same if block?
Do you really want to continue if file $1 exists?

Here's my attempt to make it at least run. Not sure if it will do exactly what you want but it's more readable and executable code.

Is this more like what you want?

**IMPROVED VERSION OF ORIGINAL CODE:**

```
#/bin/bash
B1="${1}_bck1"
B2="${1}_bck2"
if [ -e $1 ]; then 
    echo "The file already exists"
    exit 0
fi
if [ -e $B1 ]; then
    cp $B1 $B2
    echo $1
    cp $1 $B1 
    mv $B1 test
else
    echo "The file does not exist"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: thanks i went and added that but it still didnt change anything, i now get a token else error in line 20 which is for my error message if my file doesnt exist

Comment: OK I've completed my edits. Since I don't totally understand the objective I will leave it at this which should at least run or be close to running and actually doing something :-)

Comment: thank you so much for helping me out, but i still am having trouble getting my cp to work, when the program runs it should create another backup of the file entered. say i enter A.test if its already in directory it should then create a A.test_bck1, but when it runs i see no change or added files in my directory is that because the file is not moved there and merely copy and dumped after the file is ran

Comment: I can't go much further into this answer to the point of designing the whole thing.